# unityには標準で対応しているデータベースはないのでしょうか

Tags: unity3d, game-development

unityで大量のデータを管理しようと思っているのですが、
データベースを取り扱う公式のリファレンスが見当たりません。

ゲーム開発の文化では大量のデータはどのように管理しているのでしょうか。
csvなどのテキストベースのファイルに頼っているのでしょうか。

ウェブアプリケーションやネイティブアプリケーションではMySQLやSQLiteを当たり前のように使っていたので、戸惑っています。

Answer (score 4):

Unityではデフォルトではデータを管理するシステムは存在していません。

類似としてPlayerPrefが存在しています。
http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

巨大なデータを扱う場合は技術者にもよると思いますが、
Jsonだったり、CSVが一般的だと思います。
※Xmlは速度面の関係であまりよしとはしていません。
他にScriptableObjectあたりでしょうか。

Unity5.3からJsonがサポートされたようです。
(試していませんのでこれ以上のことは控えます)
それ以前のバージョンだとMiniJsonを使えば解決すると思います。

私の場合、Jsonデータを暗号化して保存しています。
一部、簡易なフラグ保存に関してはPlayerPrefを利用しています。

その他、サーバーサイド(MySQL)にまかせてしまう、というのもひとつの手段だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

標準ではありませんが下記のサイトを参考に SQLiteを Unityで利用しています。 Unity Editorや iOS, Mac OSでも動作しています。

参考
https://github.com/Busta117/SQLiteUnityKit
http://bribser.co.jp/blog/sqliteunitykit/